# Adding Steam Library Folder fails with "Steam library folder is not writable" after reformatting drive

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I recently reformatted a Solid State Drive (labeld D:) in my computer. Previously the SSD had Windows 10 installed, as I was dual booting Windows 10 & 11. I also had Steam games installed to it.

After reformatting, when I try to re-add a Steam library folder to the drive it fails with "Steam library folder is not writable". Currently the drive is empty, so there shouldn't even be a Steam folder to write to.

Why can't I add a Steam library folder to my empty drive?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because the drive had an existing Steam library folder before it was reformatted and assigned the same drive letter (D:). Steam still had the old library path saved and was looking for it on the new blank-drive.

To resolve the issue, I located the old path file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\libraryfolders.vdf`. I then re-created the Steam folder that was being used before the drive was formatted (`D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam`). After restarting Steam, the folder now correctly displays in my Steam Library.

[Thanks to KRoman47 for the solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/z68572/new_steam_library_must_be_writeable_error_on_new/jvvb2cn/).

[image: text file showing library folder paths]